# Is it possible to create a silent installer on a stock ROM rooted device?

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

I have been wondering if it is possible to create a silent installer on a stock ROM on a rooted device?
I have seen an app : Linux terminal emulator this app runs shell commands on android.
When I run :

1. su -
2. pm install myapk.apk

on this emulator It installs the apk silently. I was wondering how is this app able to install an apk silently. My device is rooted, and has a stock ROM.

I was wondering if this app can do this, cant we write our own android app to install apks silently wothout System signature files of the ROM?

EDIT: By silently I mean install an app without user prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You can ( in a very hackish way ) install apps silently using adb. You have to enable USB Debugging, but just push the APK to /data/app. ie:

> adb push MyApp.apk /data/app
>
> adb install MyApp.apk (cleaner way)

The second command MAY prompt for an installation. But you can try both. Hope it helps to you.

Comment: Thanks but I have to run it from device.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an open source library to run the command as root. Check out the following libraries:

https://github.com/Stericson/RootTools

https://github.com/SpazeDog/rootfw

https://github.com/Chainfire/libsuperuser

https://github.com/dschuermann/superuser-commands

Or do it yourself:

```
Process su = null;
try {
    su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    String cmd = "pm install /path/to/the/apk\n";
    su.getOutputStream().write(cmd.getBytes());
    String exit = "exit\n";
    su.getOutputStream().write(exit.getBytes());
    su.waitFor();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (su != null) {
        su.destroy();
    }
}
```